# ¿Cómo agregar un primer valor "seleccione" a un campo desplegable en un formulario que obtiene sus datos de MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola quisiera poner un valor que diga "seleccione" en la lista que trae desde mysql. Gracias!

```
<div class="form-group  col-lg-6">
     <select name="eaccount" class="form-control">
           <?php while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($AccountExpense)){ ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $col['AccountId'];?>"><?php echo $col['AccountName'];?></option>
           <?php } ?>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente agrega una opción más manualmente antes de que iteres las opciones que traes desde tu base de datos.

```
<option value="0">Seleccione</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es antes de hacer el `foreach` de **MySQL** setear un valor estático a la etiqueta `<option>`, de la siguiente manera:

```
<select name="eaccount" class="form-control">
    //Se agrega un option sin value que muestre la etiqueta deseada
    <option value="">Seleccione un valor</option>
    <?php while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($AccountExpense)){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $col['AccountId'];?>"><?php echo $col['AccountName'];?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes del código **PHP** agrega un **OPTION** más:

```
<select name="eaccount" class="form-control">
<option value="0">Seleccione</option>
 <?php while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($AccountExpense)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $col['AccountId'];?>">
<?php echo $col['AccountName'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Las respuestas de los compañeros son válidas, pero me permito sugerir esta otra posibilidad que comprende lo siguiente:

- Concatenar todo el contenido del `select` en una sola variable. El código queda más legible y más elegante. La mezcla constante de código PHP/HTML produce un código difícil de leer, revisar, depurar, comprender.
- Si quieres que siempre aparezca esa opción seleccionada cuando se cargue el `select`, te puedes valer del atributo `selected`.

El código quedaría así, construyendo el `select` dentro de un bloque de código PHP:

```
<div class="form-group  col-lg-6">  
    <?php 
         $strHTML='<select name="eaccount" class="form-control">';
         #Para concatenar valores en una cadena se usa .=
         $strHTML.='<option value="0" selected>--Seleccione--</option>';

            while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($AccountExpense)){ 
                 $strHTML.='<option value="'.$col['AccountId'].'">'.$col['AccountName'].'</option>';
            }
        $strHTML.='</select>';
        #Se puede seguir concatenando, o terminar aquí si no hay más código PHP
        echo $strHTML;
    ?>     
</div>
```